The localization of the modul of homomorphisms
I want to be able to better understand the localization of homomorphisms $f:N \rightarrow M$ by considering them as the localization of $f$ in the ring $S^{-1}Hom(N,M)$.
for that, I would be very nice if $S^{-1}Hom(N,M)$ was to be isomorphic to $Hom(S^{-1}N,S^{-1}M)$.
However, I'm not sure that's the case - considering the homomorphism between that sends $f/s$ to be $\frac{f}{s}(\frac{x}{t})=\frac{f(x)}{st}$.
this is clearly an isomorphism and it is bijective, however, It doesn't seem to be surjective.
Are there any important cases (for specific S, perhaps) in which $S^{-1}Hom(N,M)$ is isomorphic to $Hom(S^{-1}N,S^{-1}M)$? if not, is there another way to look at a localization of a homomorphism as a localization of an element in the homomorphism modul?

See this Stacks Project tag. The important case proved there requires $M$ to be finitely presented and nothing else.
